# Django URLs giving error The current path, carmodels/Tata/ZEST/XE Petrol, didn't match any of these

Tags: django, django-urls

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home_view, name='home'),
    url(r'^home/', home_view, name='home'),
    url(r'^search/', search, name='search'),
    url(r'^select/', search, name='select'),
    url('ajax/home_view/',home_view, name='ajax_load_models'),
    url(r'^carmodels/(?P<product_make>\w+)/(?P<model_name>\w+)/(?P<variant>\w+)/$', search, name='product_detail'),
    ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My href link in html

```
 <a href="/carmodels/{{ item.product_make }}/{{ item.model_name }}/{{ item.variant }}" class="card-title">{{ item.product_make }} {{ item.model_name }}  {{ item.variant }} </a>
```

I am new to django,could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?
Or how to write multiple slashes in url

Comment: which is your django version?

Comment: `/$` expects a `/` in the url please try once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to avoid using hardcoded URLs to prevent having errors like this. Since you have specified a `name` for your `url`s, you can refer to it in the template like this:

```py
<a href="{% url 'product_detail' item.product_make item.model_name item.variant %}" class="card-title">{{ item.product_make }} {{ item.model_name }}  {{ item.variant }} </a>
```

This way you don't have to worry about writing the exact same URL. You can learn more about it by taking a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).